# Which European countries require an Airside Transit visa (Chinese citizen)?

Tags: international-travel, transit-visas

I booked a return flight to the Republic of Ireland that has a layover in London Heathrow. I just learned that I need to get a standard visa for the UK just for this layover as I am from China. This is not possible given the time available. I have the option to rebook the flights through Paris and Geneva. Can anyone confirm that these airports do not require an airside transit visa for Chinese citizens?

What other European countries can I try to use instead of the UK for layovers in the future?

Comment: For a same-day layover in LHR you need a DATV, not a standard visa (visitor visa).

Comment: According to this website, I need a standard visa https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/china/transit/republic_of_ireland

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that your destination was the Republic of Ireland inside the Common Travel Area and  EU. It would be best to include final destination in question

Comment: Why don't you qualify for transit without visa as described in the link in your comment?

Comment: I need a BIVS visa to be exempt but I can only get a BIVS visa in China. I am currently not residing in China.

Comment: Do you mean that you could rebook to an itinerary with stops in both Paris and Geneva or you could rebook to stop in either one of those (but not the other)?

Comment: I could re-book to stop in both.

Answer (score 2):

> **Which European countries require an Airside Transit visa [for a] Chinese citizen?**

### France doesn't.

You should be OK via Paris CDG if you do not leave the international zone of the airport.

According to the [French Government Visa Advice](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/what-type-of-visa-do-i-need-to)

> **If you are transiting through an airport in France to travel to an airport outside the Schengen Area without leaving the International Zone of the French airport**
>
> As a foreign national, you do not enter the Schengen Area. In principle, you are not subject to entry visa requirements, with some exceptions. Certain nationalities are subject to visa requirements to transit through an airport in France (Airport Transit Visa or ATV).

China is not one of the countries listed among those whose nationals need an ATV.